# FileMaker Pro 9 Client + FileMaker Server 11 + Windows 7: Print Issues

Tags: windows-7, printing, filemaker

Setup:

- Several computers running FileMaker Pro 9 on Windows 7 Professional x64
- FileMaker Server Advanced 11 on OSX 10.6
- Office printers set up over TCP/IP

Seemingly at random, FileMaker will decide not to print. Regardless of whether the print job is called from a script or from clicking File -> Print, and regardless of which printer is selected, on occasion an error message will appear that reads something like

> FileMaker cannot print, because this printer is not connected to a port.

Which is ridiculous. I can print from any other application when this happens, and a restart of FileMaker seems to clear up the issue. There are no issues with any of the printers in any other applications, and this only happens once in awhile... but it usually decides to happen while I'm out of the office and a customer is waiting on an invoice.

Trying to print from any printer results in the same error message showing up.

I am having trouble reproducing this error, too... which makes it even more difficult to diagnose. It has happened on several computers now, too (all of which have almost identical hardware and are set up similarly).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very odd that File->Print does not work, however if you're using printer settings stored in scripts you need to make sure that the saved printer is named the same on all workstations.

Comment: They are. What's strange is that most of the time, it works - but every now and then, it just *doesn't* and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking into this, there is a partial solution of sometimes setting Filemaker to run in Compatibility Mode.  But I've bumped into this issue frequently with FM and it is one of the most annoying issues with this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into a printer plug-in. FileMaker has always had problems with printing and I think you'll find that you have much better control and consistency with a plug-in.

I've used a few different ones and haven't found that any one is more stable than another but I feel that [Dracoventions plug-in](http://www.dracoventions.com/products/2empowerFM/family/print.php) is the best for the money.